# How do I search a table for multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, select

So this is my first question on stackoverflow and I've searched for day's but can't find the results I am looking for.  I'm not looking for someone to write the code for me as I prefer to figure it out on my own, but I am looking for some assistance on finding how to do it.

My problem is I don't know how to word my search for what I'm looking for and this is what I want to do. I want to be able to search a MySQL database by using keywords such as "U10 Mustangs" where U10 would be data in a row called 'divisions' and Mustangs would be data in a row called 'club', I know I can use the OR statement like this

```
(`division` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`club` LIKE '%".$query."%')
```

but that only allows me to search by division or club not both. So basically I'm looking for a tutorial to show me how I can search by more than one keyword. I'm sure I'm wording this wrong and that's why I'm unable to find what I want.

I'm new to MySQL and PHP so please be understanding if this makes no sense!

**UPDATE********
here is my search code:

```
    <body>
<?php include 'menu.php';?>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="searchcontainer" style="width: 55%; height: 132px;">
<fieldset style="width: 330px"><legend>Search Criteria</legend>
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
<td>Enter Search</td><td>&nbsp; <input type="text" name="query"/></td><td>  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="table_button" value="Search" action="search.php"/></td>
<br />
</form>
</fieldset><br/>
<fieldset><legend>Search Results</legend>
<?php
        include 'connect/local_connect.php';

    $query = $_POST['query']; 
    // gets value sent over search form

   // $min_length = 3;
   // you can set minimum length of the query if you want

   // if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players
            WHERE (`team_name` LIKE '%".$query."%' AND `division` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`last_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`division` LIKE '%".$query."%') ORDER by id ASC") or die(mysql_error());

        // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `first_name`, `any`
        // players is the name of our table



        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "<font color=red>No Results!</font>";
      ?><br/><br/>
      <?php

    }
   // else{ // if query length is less than minimum
   //     echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
   // }


        // Define $color=1 
        $color="1";
        echo '<table width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
        echo '<th>ID</th><th>Club</th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Division</th>';
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

        echo "<tr bgcolor='#fff000'>
        <td><center>".$rows['id']."</td></center><td><center>".$rows['club']."</center></td><td><center>".$rows['last_name']."</td></center><td><center>".$rows['first_name']."</center></td></td><td><center>".$rows['division']."</center></td></td></tr>";       
        }




        echo '</table>';
        mysql_close();
        ?>

</fieldset>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: So you want to search by individual words? You could split the string in the " ". In PHP it would be done with `explode(" ", $String);`, however in mysql I'm not sure but that might help you get started.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Thank you, I was actually hoping someone could point me in the direction of a good tutorial as I've read though a lot of questions on here and other sites and still haven't found a way to do this as I'm sure I'm asking the question wrong. Basically I want to enter something like U10 Mustangs in a search box and get a result back with all the division 10 Mustangs. As U10 is a division and mustangs is a club.

Comment: It sounds like you want some kind of full text search if you want a generic search box.

Comment: Seriously? a down vote on my first question on here? Makes me never want to come back here again!

Comment: I think you are putting too much weight on a number based on one person's opinion, at the expense of ignoring all the people trying to be helpful.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not ignoring the help from anybody, I appreciate the time anybody takes to assist me. It's a bit irritating to see someone would down vote a question from someone trying to learn?

Comment: @user2587858 I think you were logged in as mike, as your answer above posted as him. Or did he answer for you?

Comment: @Jason Told u I didn't know what I was doing!

Comment: @user2587858 how about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482842/multi-word-search-in-php-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Are yu looking for [concat](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm)

```
where CONCAT(`division`,' ',`club`) like '%".$query."%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to create a full text index on division and club like this `FULLTEXT (club,division)` 
and search using query like this

```
SELECT * FROM db
WHERE MATCH (club,division)
AGAINST ('search');
```

Answer (score 0):

> '...but that only allows me to search by division or club *not both...'*

You can split your search string in words and then use a condition like this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE (division LIKE '%U10%' AND club LIKE '%Mustang%')
    OR (division LIKE '%Mustang%' AND club LIKE '%U10%')
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6f06/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's close but I still want to be able to search by division or club by them selves as well. Based on what you have above can I do something like this? `WHERE (division LIKE '%".$query"%' AND club LIKE '.$query"%')`

Comment: @user2447848 Technically you can but IMHO it won't produce any meaningful result. Now in order to save some valuable time on guessing and help you get your answer faster please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17916061/edit) your question and add relevant sample data (it can be a few rows of data), sample search keywords, and desired outcome based on both.

Comment: @peterm sorry I had a friend post my code as I couldn't do it from my phone so it shows as his account. but I don't see the edit with the code so I'm not sure if he posted it yet. Either way it will be there.

Comment: @user2587858 That's good that you posted your code but it not much help. I asked for relevant **sample data** (actual or fake rows of data), sample search string, **and desired outcome** after such search.

Comment: @peterm I'm not sure how to do that. Sorry, I don't want to waste your time, I'll try to research this on my own some more based on the info I've gotten from this question so far. I appreciate your help.